# Different errors while compiling, depending on distribution

Tags: errors, cross-referencing, compiling, urls

When compiling my TeX document in PCTeX the **_** in the bibliography url's appear as **“˙**. When compiling it in TeXworks the **_** appears fine, but all the table references appear as **??**. Any ideas to how I can compile my document without any errors?

Included packages are:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\usepackage{multirow, float, eurosym, booktabs, subfigure, subfig, caption, setspace, fixltx2e, amssymb, pbox, pdfpages}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[inner=3.5cm, outer=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

Comment: IIRC, PCTeX has its own packages, i.e. is a TeX distribution. I'm quite sure you have a different TeX distribution installed (e.g. TeX Live) where TeXWorks refers for packages. So probably the version of PCTeX packages are different from the ones of your second distribution and that's why you obtain a different result when compiling with different programs.

Comment: @karlkoeller is almost certainly correct, but without more detail it's very hard to be sure. We'll need a full MWE and some log file information to help further: please edit the question to include this. Also, do you have only PCTeX installed or also another TeX system used by TeXworks?